# WPF Custom control with ContextMenu ItemCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, custom-controls, itemcollection

I'm trying to create something like expandable button - button with context menu above, which will open by left mouse button click. Only thing I still can't finishing up is items property, which could be setting up in WPF XAML designer like for `ContextMenu` control. So, as far as I can understand, that means I need to use `ItemCollection` type for my property. Ok. Let's take a look on my component:

```
public partial class MenuButton : Button
{
    private readonly ContextMenu Menu;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MenuItems", typeof(ItemCollection), typeof(ContextMenu), new PropertyMetadata(default(ItemCollection), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSomeMenuItemsPropertyChanged)));

    public ItemCollection MenuItems
    {
        get => (ItemCollection)GetValue(MenuItemsProperty);
        set => SetValue(MenuItemsProperty, value);
    }

    public MenuButton()
    {
        MenuItems = new DataGrid().Items; // I really need to do it - otherwise I'll get an error

        Menu = new ContextMenu
        {
            HasDropShadow = false,
            PlacementTarget = this,
            Placement = PlacementMode.Top,
        };

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

        Menu.Width = ActualWidth;
        Menu.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private static void OnSomeMenuItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (target is ContextMenu menu)
        {
            menu.ItemsSource = (ItemCollection)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't 'catch' the `OnSomeMenuItemsPropertyChanged` - breakpoint does not work here. So, that means this mechanism is wrong.
How can I fix that? Should I use `OnItemsChanged` and `OnItemsCollectionChanged` events instead (like for `ObservableCollection`) to handle the changes of the property? Or maybe something else?

Comment: if you are using menu.ItemsSource, then your dependency property can simply have IEnumerable type

Comment: @ASh Yes, I know. But this way I can't add items via WPF XAML designer, which I want to do.

Comment: @ASh This is what I mean: https://ibb.co/LhdssP5

Comment: Usally, the third parameter of `DependencyProperty.Register` method is type of class which has that `DependencyProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally I found the solution. I don't claim that this is the best practice, but maybe it will be useful for someone:

```
public partial class MenuButton : Button
{
    private readonly ContextMenu Menu;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MenuItems", typeof(ItemCollection), typeof(MenuButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(ItemCollection), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSomeMenuItemsPropertyChanged)));

    public ItemCollection MenuItems
    {
        get => (ItemCollection)GetValue(MenuItemsProperty);
        set => SetValue(MenuItemsProperty, value);
    }

    public MenuButton()
    {
        Menu = new ContextMenu
        {
            HasDropShadow = false,
            PlacementTarget = this,
            Placement = PlacementMode.Top,
        };
        MenuItems = new DataGrid().Items;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

        Menu.Width = ActualWidth;
        Menu.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private static void OnSomeMenuItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuButton = target as MenuButton;
        menuButton.Menu.ItemsSource = (ItemCollection)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```